# Парсинг - не могу спарсить определенный сайт

Tags: python, html, парсер, scrapy

Я новичок в парсинге, сейчас столкнулся с такой проблемой, когда пытаюсь спарсить всю страницу "https://ru.wargaming.net/shop/wot/vehicles/", получаеться вот такое:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var
  tpc = "8f5d88420c6463f7e7bb633728d86e84", chk = "0001";
!function(n){"use strict";function d(n,t){var r=(65535&n)+(65535&t);return(n>>16)+(t>>16)+(r>>16)<<16|65535&r}function f(n,t,r,e,o,u){return d((u=d(d(t,n),d(e,u)))<<o|u>>>32-o,r)}function l(n,t,r,e,o,u,c){return f(t&r|~t&e,n,t,o,u,c)}function g(n,t,r,e,o,u,c){return f(t&e|r&~e,n,t,o,u,c)}function v(n,t,r,e,o,u,c){return f(t^r^e,n,t,o,u,c)}function m(n,t,r,e,o,u,c){return f(r^(t|~e),n,t,o,u,c)}function c(n,t){var r,e,o,u;n[t>>5]|=128<<t%32,n[14+(t+64>>>9<<4)]=t;for(var c=1732584193,f=-271733879,i=-1732584194,a=271733878,h=0;h<n.length;h+=16)c=l(r=c,e=f,o=i,u=a,n[h],7,-680876936),a=l(a,c,f,i,n[h+1],12,-389564586),i=l(i,a,c,f,n[h+2],17,606105819),f=l(f,i,a,c,n[h+3],22,-1044525330),c=l(c,f,i,a,n[h+4],7,-176418897),a=l(a,c,f,i,n[h+5],12,1200080426),i=l(i,a,c,f,n[h+6],17,-1473231341),f=l(f,i,a,c,n[h+7],22,-45705983),c=l(c,f,i,a,n[h+8],7,1770035416),a=l(a,c,f,i,n[h+9],12,-1958414417),i=l(i,a,c,f,n[h+10],17,-42063),f=l(f,i,a,c,n[h+11],22,-1990404162),c=l(c,f,i,a,n[h+12],7,1804603682),a=l(a,c,f,i,n[h+13],12,-40341101),i=l(i,a,c,f,n[h+14],17,-1502002290),c=g(c,f=l(f,i,a,c,n[h+15],22,1236535329),i,a,n[h+1],5,-165796510),a=g(a,c,f,i,n[h+6],9,-1069501632),i=g(i,a,c,f,n[h+11],14,643717713),f=g(f,i,a,c,n[h],20,-373897302),c=g(c,f,i,a,n[h+5],5,-701558691),a=g(a,c,f,i,n[h+10],9,38016083),i=g(i,a,c,f,n[h+15],14,-660478335),f=g(f,i,a,c,n[h+4],20,-405537848),c=g(c,f,i,a,n[h+9],5,568446438),a=g(a,c,f,i,n[h+14],9,-1019803690),i=g(i,a,c,f,n[h+3],14,-187363961),f=g(f,i,a,c,n[h+8],20,1163531501),c=g(c,f,i,a,n[h+13],5,-1444681467),a=g(a,c,f,i,n[h+2],9,-51403784),i=g(i,a,c,f,n[h+7],14,1735328473),c=v(c,f=g(f,i,a,c,n[h+12],20,-1926607734),i,a,n[h+5],4,-378558),a=v(a,c,f,i,n[h+8],11,-2022574463),i=v(i,a,c,f,n[h+11],16,1839030562),f=v(f,i,a,c,n[h+14],23,-35309556),c=v(c,f,i,a,n[h+1],4,-1530992060),a=v(a,c,f,i,n[h+4],11,1272893353),i=v(i,a,c,f,n[h+7],16,-155497632),f=v(f,i,a,c,n[h+10],23,-1094730640),c=v(c,f,i,a,n[h+13],4,681279174),a=v(a,c,f,i,n[h],11,-358537222),i=v(i,a,c,f,n[h+3],16,-722521979),f=v(f,i,a,c,n[h+6],23,76029189),c=v(c,f,i,a,n[h+9],4,-640364487),a=v(a,c,f,i,n[h+12],11,-421815835),i=v(i,a,c,f,n[h+15],16,530742520),c=m(c,f=v(f,i,a,c,n[h+2],23,-995338651),i,a,n[h],6,-198630844),a=m(a,c,f,i,n[h+7],10,1126891415),i=m(i,a,c,f,n[h+14],15,-1416354905),f=m(f,i,a,c,n[h+5],21,-57434055),c=m(c,f,i,a,n[h+12],6,1700485571),a=m(a,c,f,i,n[h+3],10,-1894986606),i=m(i,a,c,f,n[h+10],15,-1051523),f=m(f,i,a,c,n[h+1],21,-2054922799),c=m(c,f,i,a,n[h+8],6,1873313359),a=m(a,c,f,i,n[h+15],10,-30611744),i=m(i,a,c,f,n[h+6],15,-1560198380),f=m(f,i,a,c,n[h+13],21,1309151649),c=m(c,f,i,a,n[h+4],6,-145523070),a=m(a,c,f,i,n[h+11],10,-1120210379),i=m(i,a,c,f,n[h+2],15,718787259),f=m(f,i,a,c,n[h+9],21,-343485551),c=d(c,r),f=d(f,e),i=d(i,o),a=d(a,u);return[c,f,i,a]}function i(n){for(var t="",r=32*n.length,e=0;e<r;e+=8)t+=String.fromCharCode(n[e>>5]>>>e%32&255);return t}function a(n){var t=[];for(t[(n.length>>2)-1]=void 0,e=0;e<t.length;e+=1)t[e]=0;for(var r=8*n.length,e=0;e<r;e+=8)t[e>>5]|=(255&n.charCodeAt(e/8))<<e%32;return t}function e(n){for(var t,r="0123456789abcdef",e="",o=0;o<n.length;o+=1)t=n.charCodeAt(o),e+=r.charAt(t>>>4&15)+r.charAt(15&t);return e}function r(n){return unescape(encodeURIComponent(n))}function o(n){return i(c(a(n=r(n)),8*n.length))}function u(n,t){return function(n,t){var r,e=a(n),o=[],u=[];for(o[15]=u[15]=void 0,16<e.length&&(e=c(e,8*n.length)),r=0;r<16;r+=1)o[r]=909522486^e[r],u[r]=1549556828^e[r];return t=c(o.concat(a(t)),512+8*t.length),i(c(u.concat(t),640))}(r(n),r(t))}function t(n,t,r){return t?r?u(t,n):e(u(t,n)):r?o(n):e(o(n))}"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(function(){return t}):"object"==typeof module&&module.exports?module.exports=t:n.md5=t}(this);
function a0_0x5356(_0x5370f2,_0x431c21){var _0x170cce=a0_0xa9db();return a0_0x5356=function(_0x46aa87,_0x55f5c7){_0x46aa87=_0x46aa87-(0x11ab+-0x1*0x1ec1+0xda0);var _0x4984bc=_0x170cce[_0x46aa87];return _0x4984bc;},a0_0x5356(_0x5370f2,_0x431c21);}var a0_0x12311a=a0_0x5356;function a0_0xa9db(){var _0x201b7b=['onload','230502LeGmSK','reload','520pDolvA','7096mRmMTi','location','setTimeout','171330KfNWMu','6561faTUqt','1253QgTtub','toString','; path=/; max-age=3600;','26697OCMBPm','16088ixpZIS','1928BiCRjh','cookie','26bcBdvH'];a0_0xa9db=function(){return _0x201b7b;};return a0_0xa9db();}(function(_0x5d7a87,_0x1c4408){var _0x432461=a0_0x5356,_0x5dcf2a=_0x5d7a87();while(!![]){try{var _0x28ec61=-parseInt(_0x432461(0x8e))/(-0x1bc2+0x6e5+0x14de)*(-parseInt(_0x432461(0x90))/(0x1e3b+0x13cc+0xd*-0x3d9))+parseInt(_0x432461(0x8c))/(-0x482*0x1+-0x10c0+0x1545)+-parseInt(_0x432461(0x8d))/(-0x87d+-0x5*-0x229+-0x24c)+parseInt(_0x432461(0x98))/(0x11aa+-0x4*0x79a+0xcc3)+-parseInt(_0x432461(0x92))/(-0xa1*-0x13+-0x29*0xc8+0x141b)+parseInt(_0x432461(0x9a))/(-0x1*-0xf71+-0x15a1+0x637)*(parseInt(_0x432461(0x95))/(0x562+-0x22f6+0x1d9c))+-parseInt(_0x432461(0x99))/(0x259d*-0x1+0x587*0x4+0xf8a)*(-parseInt(_0x432461(0x94))/(0x39*0x8f+0x454+-0x3*0xc0b));if(_0x28ec61===_0x1c4408)break;else _0x5dcf2a['push'](_0x5dcf2a['shift']());}catch(_0x30a5ef){_0x5dcf2a['push'](_0x5dcf2a['shift']());}}}(a0_0xa9db,0xb4b*-0x4d+0x57f18+0x14b7e*0x1),window[a0_0x12311a(0x91)]=function(_0x1af3e9){var _0x41f082=a0_0x12311a;document['cookie']='pss_b7f8235d='+tpc+_0x41f082(0x8b);for(i=-0x8*-0x1e8+-0x3bf+-0xb81;;i++){if(md5(tpc+'::'+i)[_0x41f082(0x8a)]()['startsWith'](chk)){document[_0x41f082(0x8f)]='pss_a05a4e6e='+i+'; path=/; max-age=3600;',window[_0x41f082(0x97)](function(){var _0x362873=_0x41f082;window[_0x362873(0x96)][_0x362873(0x93)]();},-0x1*0x71b+0x1118+0xb*-0xbb);break;}}});
</script>
<title>Please wait...</title>
<body bgcolor="#171717"></body>
</head>
</html>
```

Делал все с помощью Scrapy:

```
import scrapy


class PostsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "wgshop"

    start_urls = [
        'https://ru.wargaming.net/shop/wot/vehicles/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = 'wgshop.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Когда пытаюсь получить информацию через css, xpath селекторы в scrapy shell, возвращает пустые скобки. Заходил под своим аккаунтом, результат такой же. Пробовал выполнить javascript на странице, но либо не так пробовал либо не в этом дело. Уже не первый раз такае, не только на этом сайте. Просто хочу понять в чем проблема.

Comment: Динамический сайт селениюм вам в помощь

Comment: сайты имеют законное право мешать их парсить.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь wargaming твое API имеется